# V-for to show specific properties of objects

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am making many tables, so I made a table-making component. There are only 3 different things per table:

1. the object (an array of objects. 1 row per object)
2. the headers specific for that table
3. the object properties I specifically want to display

My component:

```
Vue.component('table-component', {
  props: {
    headers: Array,
    data_for_rows: Object,
    data_properties_to_display: Array,
  },
  template: `
  <div>
    <table class="table-hover">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th v-for='item in headers'>{{item}}</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr v-for='object in data_for_rows'>
              <td v-for='property in data_properties_to_display'>{{object.property}}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
`
});
```

The HTML itself:

```
                    <table-component :headers="['Party','Members','Votes With Party %']" data_for_rows="glance_data"
                        :data_properties_to_display="['partyName','memberCount','percentage']">
                    </table-component>
```

The goal is to be able to print the properties values within an object (specifically by passing the object itself and the properties-to-be-printed as separate props to the component). Can I?

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: The object property values aren't being shown at all. Essentially I want to do something like senateMember.party  to be shown  as the table data  by passing the property name AND the object as separate props to the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{object.property}}` would be looking for a property named `property` on the `object` instance in that nested loop, right? I'm thinking you might want something more like `{{object[ property ]}}`.

Comment: YES!... combined with changing the html to be ":data_for_rows="this.glance_data" as well. Thank you!

Comment: `this.` is not necessary, `:data_for_rows="glance_data"` is ok

Comment: @niccord Indeed it isn't! Thank you!